# Bubble sort issue

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

Currently studying software engineering at college (first year) and made a program where the user enters how many entries there will be and then they input the times for each entry and it is sorted in descending order.

The problem I am having is when I enter a large number for the first input it doesn't sort correctly but the rest do. It would be great if someone could help me out with this and sorry for the noob question:P

The entire code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int TotalSize = 0;

void getSpeed(int *CalculationTime, int NoOfCalculations)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfCalculations; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the speed of calculation " << i + 1 << "(Ms): "; cin >>      CalculationTime[i];
    }
}

void sort_speeds(int *CalculationTime, int NoOfCalculations)
{
    // Sorting speeds in decending order
    bool swapped = true;
    int i, j = 0;
    int temp;

    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (i = 1; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)
        {
            if (CalculationTime[i] > CalculationTime[i + 1])
            {
                temp = CalculationTime[i];
                CalculationTime[i] = CalculationTime[i + 1];
                CalculationTime[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Output times decending order
    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfCalculations; i++)
    {
        cout << CalculationTime[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Declaring & Initializing variables
    int NoOfCalculations = 0;
    int *CalculationTime = new int[NoOfCalculations];

    // Getting user input
    cout << "How many calculations are there? "; cin >> NoOfCalculations;
    getSpeed(CalculationTime, NoOfCalculations);

    // Sorting and displaying times 
    sort_speeds(CalculationTime, NoOfCalculations);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you been told you're not allowed to use `std::vector`, by the way?

Comment: No not even sure what that is/does

Comment: What are you doing with int *CalculationTime = new int[NoOfCalculations];?

Comment: Oh dear. Writing C++ without using the standard library is never a good idea, though it still seems to be common in software courses. Basically, it is an automatically resizing array which deals with its own memory allocation and deallocation, shielding you from basic mistakes like the ones you've made.

Answer (score 1):

You've never compare first element of your array with anything - `for (i = 1; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)`

Comment: Thanks! stupid error on my part, forgot that arrays start at a position of 0 rather than 1 in c++

Comment: @user3686991 but you did it right in `getSpeed` and your "output times" loop!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `for (i = 1; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)` You are starting at position 1, start at position 0 and it fixes the problem. `for (i = 0; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)`

Answer (score -1):

```
// Declaring & Initializing variables
int NoOfCalculations = 0;
int *CalculationTime = new int[NoOfCalculations];

// Getting user input
cout << "How many calculations are there? "; cin >> NoOfCalculations;
```

Bzzzt. You allocate a zero-element array, and then don't reallocate it. I bet if you entered a large enough number for your number of calculations, your program would crash.

Really, you want to be using `std::vector`, an extremely useful datastructure, the use of which is a bit outside of the scope of this answer. Basically, you can do stuff like this:

```
std::vector<int> getSpeeds(int NoOfCalculations)
{
    std::vector<int> speeds;

    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfCalculations; i++)
    {
        int speed;
        std::cout << "Please enter the speed of calculation " << i + 1 << "(Ms): ";
        std::cin >> speed;
        speeds.push_back(speed);
    }

    return speeds;
}
```

You can use the returned vector almost exactly as if it were an array:

```
std::vector<int> speeds = getSpeeds(10);;
if (CalculationTime[3] > CalculationTime[4])
    // do something
```

Often, in a C++ application, the explicit use of pointers is a sign that you're not using the standard library, and as a result making life much, much harder for yourself.

Oh, and also:

```
for (i = 1; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)
```

You never look at `NoOfCalculations[0]` or `NoOfCalculations[i - 1]`, so you never touch the first element.

Comment: Downvotes without comment are useless and help no-one. If you can't explain what the problem is, you probably shouldn't be downviting in the first place. Going back through my old questions and answers and downviting them one after another is also the sort of thing that moderators frown upon.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (swapped)
{
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (i = 0; i < NoOfCalculations - j; i++)   //try and start i from 0. I think you are missing the first element to check
    {
        if (CalculationTime[i] > CalculationTime[i + 1])
        {
            temp = CalculationTime[i];
            CalculationTime[i] = CalculationTime[i + 1];
            CalculationTime[i + 1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
 }
```